# MouseCliked listener not always running

Tags: java, events, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener

I have a `MouseClicked` listener but sometimes it doesn't run.

However `MousePressed` or `MouseRelease` are always active.

My code :

```
mixbutton[0][0].addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
    {

        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
        {   if(flag==0) 
        {
            count++;
            if(subimage[0][1]==null)
            {
                temp=subimage[0][0];
                subimage[0][0]=subimage[0][1];
                subimage[0][1]=temp;
                mixbutton[0][0].setIcon(subimage[0][0]);
                mixbutton[0][1].setIcon(subimage[0][1]);
            }
            else if(subimage[1][0]==null)
            {
                temp=subimage[0][0];
                subimage[0][0]=subimage[1][0];
                subimage[1][0]=temp;
                mixbutton[0][0].setIcon(subimage[0][0]);
                mixbutton[1][0].setIcon(subimage[1][0]);
            }
            if(checkimage[0][0]==subimage[0][0] &&checkimage[0][1]==subimage[0][1] &&checkimage[0][2]==subimage[0][2] &&
                    checkimage[1][0]==subimage[1][0] &&checkimage[1][1]==subimage[1][1] &&checkimage[1][2]==subimage[1][2] &&
                            checkimage[2][0]==subimage[2][0] &&checkimage[2][1]==subimage[2][1]  )
            {
                jumsulabel.setText("sucess"+count);
                rankinput.setSize(400,300);rankinput.setVisible(true);
                flag=1; //
            }
        }
        }

    }
    );
```

Comment: please what do you meaning with your comment in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mouse button is pressed and the mouse is moved even for a nanosecond, and then the mouse button is released, then it will not capture the `mouseClicked` event. In such a case only `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` events are fired. You can verify this by listening to `mouseDragged` event. Between `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` events, you will find one or more `mouseDragged` events.

It's rather unusual to use `MouseListener` with Buttons. Instead use `ActionListener`.

Comment: thanks
as result i check mouse drag event.  if mouseDragged event running MouseClicked Event does not work